# How can I use Azure Storage Account with Keystone?

Tags: azure-storage, keystonejs

I have an app that I need to move to an Azure subcription. the stack is NextJs, Prisma and Keystone.

It is doing some file uploading and Keystone have built in support for s3 storage.

Is there a way to use a Azure Storage account in place of an s3?

I tried using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@k6-contrib/fields-azure but can't get it to work.

Comment: The "way to use a Azure Storage account" is to create your own field type or use someone else's, like the `fields-azure` package you've linked to. If you want help with a specific problem, post some technical details (error messages, etc.) otherwise no one will be able to help. The author of that package (gautamsi) is pretty active on Github. Maybe create an issue on the `k6-contrib` repo that the `fields-azure` package is from? https://github.com/keystonejs-contrib/k6-contrib

Comment: Managed to solve it with some help. Anyhow, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from another source and managed to solve it.

I used the package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@k6-contrib/fields-azure) but had to make some modifications.

In `keystone.ts`

Add import

```
import {AzureStorageConfig, azureStorageImage} from "@k6-contrib/fields-azure";
```

Then a config object needs to be created for the SA-connection.

```
const azConfig: AzureStorageConfig = {
    azureStorageOptions: {
        account: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME || '',
        accessKey: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY || '',
        container: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER || '',
        url: process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_HOST
            ? `${process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_HOST}${process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER}`
            : undefined,
    },
};
```

Note that this differs somewhat from the instructions at npm and in the example. The url needed to be "host/container".

Then the fields connected to the storage needed to be set. In my case the "logo" field.

```
logo: azureStorageImage({azureStorageConfig: azConfig})
```

- `AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER`

  - The name of the container in the storage account.
- `AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME`

  - The name of the storage account.
- `AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY`

  - The access key for the storage account.
- `AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_HOST`

  - The url/endpoint to the storage account.

Hope this can help someone out there with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution for others :)